# ClassCastException when running on Oracle Database JVM

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jvm

I have the following code:

```
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL(thinConnectionString);
OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) ods.getConnection();

ArrayDescriptor d = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("MDSYS.RDF_MODELS", conn);
```

When I run this code from outside Oracle's VM it works without a problem. However, when I load it on the Oracale Database JVM with `loadjava` tool and then run it inside Oracle, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.putDescriptor(PhysicalConnection.java)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:156)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:123)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:106)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:73)
    at XercesTest.Test1(XercesTest.java:46)
    at XercesTest.Test(XercesTest.java:171)
```

What is causing this problem and how to possibly fix it?

***Edit:***

When I inspect the underlying type of the connection object, I get the type `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` when running outside Oracle's VM, and `oracle.jdbc.driver.T2SConnection` when running on the server.

***Edit 2: [SOLVED]***

The issue was due to conflict in the `jdbc` driver classes; `loadjava` loaded accidentally dependency files from `ojdbc5.jar` to the database wich caused conflit with those of Oracle. Once I dropped these, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the OracleDataSource and OracleConnection classes come from? Have you tried to get the connection just by using "standard JDBC classes"?

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection")
```

It seems that your data source connection is not that what the Oracle driver expects.

Have you changed the JDBC URL accordingly?

Do other operations fail as well, or is it just the ArrayDescriptor?

Comment: Even with `DriverManager.getConnection` I am getting the same error. The JDBC URL is fine, other operations execute correctly, just ArrayDescriptor giving this error. (*note using jdbc5*).